# Why cant react set initial state based on props

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, state, es6-class, react-fiber

I have a es6 react component that I want the initial value of the state to depend on that of the passed down prop, but its value is always false:

AttachStateToProps component

```
<AttachStateToProps VALUE=false />
```

AttachStateToProps component:

```
class AttachStateToProps extends React.Component {
  state = {
    stateValue: this.props.VALUE,
  }
  render() {
    console.log('Value of Prop - ', this.props.VALUE)
    console.log('Value of State - ', this.state.stateValue)

  return null
  }
}
```

Every time the value of the prop VALUE is changed, I get:

```
`Value of Prop - false` // this changes whenever I change prop value in 
   <AttachStateToProps />
```

and

```
`Value of State - false` // this does not change accordingly.
```

I figure [it could be something to do with state/setState being async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49222715/7015414) and older [`getinitialState`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243272/using-props-to-seed-initial-state-in-react-without-using-react-createclass?rq=1) but I don't get why it.

Comment: try changing the state in componentDidMount

Comment: now it returns `true` all the time. Also eslint complains `[eslint] Do not use setState in componentDidMount (react/no-did-mount-set-state)` - i think its not a good pattern

Answer (score 10):

Initializing the state from the props in the constructor, or as a class property, will not update the state when the prop changes. However, react does detect the prop change, and rerenders the component.

**Example:**

```js
class AttachStateToProps extends React.Component {
  state = {
    stateValue: this.props.VALUE,
  }
  render() {
    console.log('Value of Prop - ', this.props.VALUE)
    console.log('Value of State - ', this.state.stateValue)

  return null
  }
}

const renderWithVal = (val) => ReactDOM.render(
  <AttachStateToProps VALUE={val} />,
  demo
);

renderWithVal(5);
renderWithVal(15);
renderWithVal(115);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

To update the state when the prop changes, you need to use a component's [lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

With React ^16.3 you can use the static [`getDerivedStateFromProps()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) method to update the state from the props (and initialize it as well):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {    
  return {
    stateValue: nextProps.VALUE,
  }
}
```

```js
class AttachStateToProps extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {    
    return {
      stateValue: nextProps.VALUE,
    }
  }
      
  render() {
    console.log('Value of Prop - ', this.props.VALUE)
    console.log('Value of State - ', this.state.stateValue)

  return null
  }
}

const renderWithVal = (val) => ReactDOM.render(
  <AttachStateToProps VALUE={val} />,
  demo
);

renderWithVal(5);
renderWithVal(15);
renderWithVal(115);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

With React versions prior to 16.3, you can use [`componentWillReceiveProps()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

Note: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated, but will work 'till version 17.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  this.setState({
    stateValue: nextProps.VALUE,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will not work without super(props) in constructor.

```
    class AttachStateToProps extends React.Component { 
constructor(props) { 
super(props); 
this.state = { stateValue: this.props.VALUE, 
} 
} 
render() { 
console.log('Value of Prop - ', this.props.VALUE) console.log('Value of State - ', this.state.stateValue) return null 
}
 }
```