# Init state with a props make my state undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I quickly created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zv9ql9po2) to explain my problem more easily.

I want that when in click on my `clickableItem` the value of the input from the `simplePopOver` component take the value from the state from the `clickableItem` component.

For that I initialize the state from `simplePopOver` with a props but the problem is that state is always equal to the init value `'initialisation'`  whereas the props has the good value (check `console.log()`). Do you have an idea ? Is it an asynchronous problem ?

I don't think my explanations are clear, but if you check the sandbox it will be more clear :)

Comment: `this.state.textInInput` , not `this.state.clickableElementText`

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Its updated Thanks :) But now the value of the `state` is always equal to the init value `'initialisation'` :( Look like an asynchronous problem

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403693/why-cant-react-set-initial-state-based-on-props ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update state based on change in props in `SimplePopover` component

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    console.log(props);
    if (props.clickableElementText !== state.prevClickableElementText) {
      return {
        prevClickableElementText: props.clickableElementText,
        textInInput: props.clickableElementText,
      }
    }
    return {
      prevClickableElementText: props.clickableElementText
    }
  }
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lpjj22zzm7)

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you :) It is a good practice to use this method ?

Comment: There are  multiple alternatives to getDerivedStateFromProps which you can use depending on your usecase. You can have a look at the documentation for more details. For your use case `getDerivedStateFromProps` is the correct alternative

Answer (score 0):

the state clickableElementText

it is not declared

Use this.state.textInInput

Comment: Please take the time to format your answer correclty

Comment: Oups little mistake I modified it :) Thanks